# Detecting iOS UI events in programmatically created controls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, events

I want to have a text input (UITextField) which I create in the main View Controller react to the user's input (specifically when they tap the keyboard's "return" key), but I can't find any way to do this.

I understand that the "usual" way to do this is to create the control in Interface Builder and use that to connect events on the control to exposed IBAction methods, but I want to do this without Interface Builder.

***Alternatively***

I can create the control in Interface Builder and have its events connected normally, but how do I then get ahold of the object to control it (I just want to be able to hide/show it and perhaps reposition in) from my code?

Again I can't find a way to do this

Either route would work for me - I really don't care how I create the UITextField.

TIA

Mike Peat

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'd been banging my head of this for about three days.  However no sooner had I posted the question, I tired going the other route again - creating the UITextField in Interface Builder, then trying to get a handle to that.  My understanding of what I was doing must have improved since my original efforts in that direction (which I think were both done on the wrong object and in the wrong place), because I got it working in just a few minutes.

Comment: As I said above, I really don't care how the darn thing gets created, so long as I can get it to work.  Creating it in Interface Builder allowed me to hook up its events (Did End On Exit and Editing Did End) to methods in my View Controller and go from there.  Thank you for your suggestions - they both look like they would work - I had looked at both approaches but didn't know how to go about implementing them... thanks to you I do now!

Answer (score 1):

You could add an observer to the notification center like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(keyPressed:) name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object: nil];
```

and implement the corresponding method:

```
-(void) keyPressed: (NSNotification*) notification
{
  NSLog([[notification object]text]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a delegate for the TextField.

```
textField.delegate = self;
```

The delegate has certain methodes that reacts to actions with the textField.

You can react to the UserInput with the delegate methode:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

It is called after the DoneKey (or whatever key you use to end the editing) is pressed

Hope this is what you are looking for